# Deploying the local host in tomcat docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry

I need to run already running localhost in my system into tomcat docker. I have used the command, tried to add the localhost into container mygit(tomcat being hosted here)

```
docker run --hostname=http://10.132.200.76:1000/ -d -p 8082:8080 --name mygit tomcat
```

Comment: `localhost` is a context-specific DNS name that refers to the current system; it can be confusing in Docker because each container is its own `localhost`, separate from the host system.  When you want to "run already running localhost", what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have an application running on localhost port. I want to deploy same localhost port through tomcat docker.